# Spinner layout refresh in expanded list

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have spinner in my extended list. What I would like to refresh layout of spinner after button is clicked. I am successful at refreshing its state to "0" position, but user still sees old value.

What I would like to know:

1. It is possible to recreate layout in expanded list?
2. How to refresh spinner layout, so user would see change and would not need to scroll down and up for that
3. Maybe a little bit of topic. It is possible to have one spinner in expanded list with different values on each child of expanded list? In example:

   **Test1**

   *sub1 SpinnerValue1*

   *sub2 SpinnerValue2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested otherwise. use other layout to achieve desired effect